# Get rgba value of an image with Matplotlib mouse event

Tags: python, matplotlib, mouseevent, imshow, rgba

I am currently looking to get the RGBA value when clicking on a matplotlib image object with imshow method.

I am able to get the coordinates x,y of the mouse event but not the intensity value from the image. Since my toolbar is displaying this information in an irritating way in real-time, I guess it should be possible but despite my efforts, I didn't manage to found how. It could be possible to get the value by taking the intensity value at the matrix coordinates in my images which is a Numpy object, but in my case, since I work with several subplots and I have no idea how to access the good objects and I am looking for a more straightforward or direct way to access it.

Is there any simple way to do that only using matplotlib libraries?

Here is a test code. I would like to obtain the RGBA value (0,0,0,1), (0,0,0,0.5) when clicking respectively on subplot 1 and 2.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

black = np.zeros((100,100,4))

for j in range(1,3):
    im = black.copy()
    im[:,:,3] = 1/j
    plt.subplot(1,2,j)
    plt.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    xdata = event.xdata
    ydata = event.ydata
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    #rgba = event.some_attributes
    print(x,y,xdata,ydata)
    #print(rgba)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to get the current subplot object and the corresponding pixel value :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

black = np.zeros((100,100,4))

for j in range(1,3):
    im = black.copy()
    im[:,:,3] = 1/j
    plt.subplot(1,2,j)
    plt.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    xdata = event.xdata
    ydata = event.ydata
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    rgba = event.inaxes.get_images()[0].get_cursor_data(event)
    print(x,y,xdata,ydata)
    print(rgba)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show(block=True)
```